# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm always getting the following error.Can somebody help me please?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.DStreamJavaFunctions.<init>(DStreamJavaFunctions.java:24)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.java:55)
    at SparkStream.main(SparkStream.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
```

When I compile the following code. I've searched the web but didn't find a solution. I've got the error when I added the saveToCassandra.

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow;

/**
 * Created by jonas on 10/10/16.
 */
public class SparkStream implements Serializable{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
                .setAppName("TwitterToCassandra")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");
;
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(5000));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("Test");

        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                ssc,
                String.class,
                String.class,
                kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.class,
                kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.class,
                kafkaParams,
                topics
        );

        JavaDStream<Tweet> createTweet = directKafkaStream.map(s -> createTweet(s._2));


        CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(createTweet)
                .writerBuilder("mykeyspace", "rawtweet", mapToRow(Tweet.class))
                .saveToCassandra();

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();

    }


    public static Tweet createTweet(String rawKafka){
        String[] splitted = rawKafka.split("\\|");
        Tweet t = new Tweet(splitted[0], splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3]);
        return t;
    }
}
```

My pom is the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sentiment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>twitter4j.org</id>
            <name>twitter4j.org Repository</name>
            <url>http://twitter4j.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0,)</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-async</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

org.apache.spark.Logging is available in Spark version 1.5.2 or lower version. It is not in the 2.0.0. Pls change versions as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: then what is the use of using higher version of spark? How to do it 2.x version spark

Comment: This fails to build: The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:jar:1.6.2 is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: Try to download from web and copy to your location. This may help to download the jar. https://jar-download.com/?search_box=spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.2.0&p=2

Answer (score 10):

The error is because you are using Spark 2.0 libraries with the connector from Spark 1.6 (which looks for the Spark 1.6 logging class. Use the 2.0.5 version of the connector.

Comment: What if you are using pyspark?

Comment: The answer is the same

Comment: Thank you @RussS seems like the best solution, I can't find how to update the connector on python, does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 6):

It's because of the missing of org.apache.spark.Logging class since 1.5.2, just like everybody say. (Only org.apache.spark.internal.Logging exists in later version... )

But it seems none of the solution against maven can solve this dependency, so I just try to add this class to lib manually. Here is my way to fixed the problem:

1. Package the scala `org.apache.spark.internal.Logging` into a public jar. Or download it from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swordsmanliu/SparkStreamingHbase/master/lib/spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar (Thanks to this host.)
2. Move the jar into your spark cluster's jars directory.
3. Submit your project again, wish it will help u.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution by changing  above mention jar.

Initially, I was having degraded jar for spark-kafka-streaming:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version></dependency>
```

I also removed multilple sl4j-log4j.jars  and log4j.jars which I had added externally from spark and kafka jar library.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using IntelliJ, just check the 'include dependencies with provided scope' box and that will fix the issue for you without mucking around with the pom or manually downloading the files.

Comment: I was using IntelliJ and this solution helped me. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Download spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar and use as --jar option

spark-submit --class com.SentimentTwiteer --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:1.6.3" --jars /root/Desktop/spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar /root/Desktop/SentimentTwiteer.jar consumerKey consumerSecret accessToken accessTokenSecret yoursearchTag

https://github.com/sinhavicky4/SentimentTwiteer

Answer (score 0):

One reason that may cause this problem is **lib and class conflict**.
I faced this problem and solved it using some **maven exclusions**:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

this pom.xml is resolve my issue:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the jar and use --jars in spark-submit ,worked for me
spark-submit --class com.SentimentTwiteer --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:1.6.3" --jars /root/Desktop/spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar  /root/Desktop/SentimentTwiteer.jar  XX XX XX XX

Answer (score 0):

Download the below Jar ,and it into you library ,and it will work as expected.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swordsmanliu/SparkStreamingHbase/master/lib/spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar

Answer (score -2):

its a version issue try with latest version

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

Missing logging Jar in your dependency jars list. Try to download "spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging" jar from mvn repository, then add it as external jar to your spark project, you don't get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging" error.
Based on scala version you can download the jar{2.10,2.11,etc}.

Comment: Why downloading and add as external jar. Why not add it as dependency directly in the pom?

Comment: Yes I agree with you comment, think if you have installed higher than spark 1.5.2 (ex 2.x.x)in your system what is the use to downloading of all jars related to 1.5.2 version, does it make sense ?, it will through an error like version compatibility.

Comment: I added jar to dependencies .still no go..                                                                    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at

Comment: Downloaded the jar and use --jars in spark-submit                              
 spark-submit --class com.SentimentTwiteer --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:1.6.3" --jars /root/Desktop/spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar  /root/Desktop/SentimentTwiteer.jar  XX XX XX XX