# Spark remote job

Tags: apache-spark

while I'm trying to submit a spark job from eclipse onto a remote hadoop cluster(yarn) getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Start with sharing code.

Comment: You are missing some dependency jars.
You can check this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287289/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-logging

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the spark version which I'm using. I'm using Spark 1.6.0 on production cluster, I cant change the version to 1.5.2

Comment: Thanks for your time mtoto, Deepan Ram. The problem is solved by downloading and saving the spark-assembly jar onto the HDFS cluster and adding this property to the eclipse code set("spark.yarn.jar" "hdfs//namenode:8020/<path of the jar>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by downloading and saving the spark-assembly jar onto the HDFS cluster and adding this property to the eclipse code set("spark.yarn.jar" "hdfs//namenode:8020/