# Eclipse: Apache Spark 2.1.1, org.apache.spark.logging couldn't be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

The error statement:

```
org.apache.spark.logging couldn't be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I read about the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files) (general to such errors). Further I found that org.apache.spark.logging is in fact not available for Spark versions > 1.5.2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287289/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-logging).

I am able to run the code by setting the spark version to 1.5.2. Is there any way to run the same code (with some changes, if required) using Spark version 2.1.1 ? I am specifically trying [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/JavaAssociationRulesExample.java) code.

I am new to maven, eclipse and spark, therefore a detailed answer explaining the stuff would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the Spark 2.1.1 so please use the below depedency to resolve the issue.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>            
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I added this dependency to the POM file, also set the spark version to 2.1.1. Have a at the ([pom](https://pastebin.com/xirXYgvN)) file. The problem persists.