# Zeppelin: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, spark-streaming, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to find trending hashtags on twitter using Spark streaming.

> os -> mac os
>
> spark-version -> 2.2.1
>
> scala-version -> 2.11.8
>
> zeppelin-version -> 0.7.3

Above tools and versions I'm using. I have added three different jars to my zeppelin notebook:

> twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar
>
> twitter4j-stream-4.0.4.jar
>
> spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.0.0.jar

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._

def setUpTwitter() = {
    import scala.io.Source
    for (line <- Source.fromFile("/Users/abhijeet/Documents/sparkscala/SparkScala/twitter.txt").getLines) {
        val fields = line.split(" ")
        if (fields.length == 2){
            System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth." + fields(0), fields(1))
        }
    }
}
setUpTwitter()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
def setupLogging() = {
    import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
}
setupLogging()
```

Upto this point in code zeppelin worked fine

`val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)`

In above line it started throwing error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils$.createStream(TwitterUtils.scala:44)
  ... 56 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 69 more
```

After that I found org.apache.spark.Logging is available in Spark version 1.5.2 or lower version. It is not in the 2.0.0.

My concern is I'm using Zeppelin. I have no pom file here or anything to change the version.

What is the way to resolve this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/linkedin/photon-ml/issues/189 logging has been removed from spark package so you will have to add external dependency for logging

Comment: can you mention the name for that jar and the version that I'm supposed to use

Comment: I'm using zeppelin and there is no maven or sbt.

Comment: It's not working( https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17 ). Is there anything above in my code that needs to be changed according to log4j or it would be the same

Comment: I give the path of the jar in Zeppelin to add it to the dependency. Like this time I added /Users/abhijeet/Downloads/log4j.....

Comment: or should I have to put the jar inside the lib folder of zeppelin source code?

Comment: Not Working Man! :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287289/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-logging is suggesting you to use lower version of spark and this one too https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/58286/noclassdeffounderror-orgapachesparklogging-using-s.html

Comment: Hey I posted the solution in the Answer. I resolved the issue

Comment: great to have helped you :)

Comment: Sorry I forget to acknowledge you because of the excitement. Thanks very much!

Comment: thats alright :)

Comment: mvnrepository its the not the official one, the official is https://search.maven.org/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/bundle
As mentioned here: https://central.sonatype.org/search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by adding the jar

> spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar

Answer (score 0):

Had issues with this and found another solution that I thought people might want to try. I had better luck using the org.apache.bahir version 2.40 if you are in a later version of spark (I'm on 3.0).

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bahir/spark-streaming-twitter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```