# How to read scylladb table in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, scylla

I am trying to read scylladb table installed one pc into pyspark dataframe on another pc.
The 2 pcs have ssh connectivity and I am able to read the table via python code, there is problem only while connecting with spark.I have used this connector:

```
--packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.3.0-s_2.11 ,
```

My spark -version = 2.3.1 , scala-version-2.11.8.

```
**First Approach**
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","192.168.0.118")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
spark=SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).appName('FinancialRecon').getOrCreate()
sqlContext =SQLContext(sc)
data=spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="datarecon",keyspace="finrecondata").load().show()
```

Resulting error:

> File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",         line 172, in load
>       File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
>       File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
>       File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.load.
>       : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging was removed in   Spark 2.0. Please check if your library is compatible with Spark 2.0
>       at         org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:646)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>       at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at                                                                          org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
>       at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
>       at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
>       ... 13 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 33 more

Another Approch that I have used is :

```
data=sc.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="datarecon",keyspace="finrecondata").load().show()
```

For this I get:

> AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'read'

Third Approach:

```
data=sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="datarecon",keyspace="finrecondata").load().show()
```

For this I get the same error as the first approach.

Please advice whether it is scylla spark connector issue or some spark   library issue  and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps :**

1.Run the spark-shell with the packages line.To configure the default Spark Configuration pass key value pairs with --conf, In my case scylla host is 172.17.0.2

```
bin/spark-shell --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=172.17.0.2 --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.3.0-s_2.11
```

2.Enable Cassandra-specific functions on the SparkContext, SparkSession, RDD, and DataFrame:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
```

3.Load data from scylla

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "my_table")
```

4.Test

```
scala> rdd.collect().foreach(println)
CassandraRow{id: 1, name: ash}
```

Comment: OP asked for PySpark

Answer (score 0):

The resulting error occurs due to a version conflict. Maybe you can solve it reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287289/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-logging).

The first approach will work because read method is available on [SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.read).