# Spark Scala Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am new to Spark scala and i was trying to create a command Line Parser Project.
After compiling it with `mvn clean package` , when I am trying to run the jar then I am getting the following Error -

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar C:\Users\patrag\Documents\Git_REpo\MyDev\Udemy\commandLineParser_0406\target\commandLineParser_0406-0.1.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    ....
```

This is how my POM.xml looks like -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.np.modulename</groupId>
  <artifactId>commandLineParser_0406</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <build-artifact>${project.artifactId}</build-artifact>
    <build.version>${project.version}</build.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.4.3</spark.version>
    <aws.redshift.jdbc.driver.version>1.2.10.1009</aws.redshift.jdbc.driver.version>
    <scoverage.plugin.version>1.3.0</scoverage.plugin.version>
    <scoverage.aggregate>true</scoverage.aggregate>
    <!-- this is latest maven version which is required by Scoverage plugin -->
    <!-- Also make sure that you specify the latest (same) maven plugin in project setting => build => maven and also probably in settings.xml-->
    <maven.version>3.5.4</maven.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.scopt</groupId>
      <artifactId>scopt_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- scala test dependency for automated test cases-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.version}</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.np.modulename.app.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <finalName>${build-artifact}-${build.version}</finalName>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--        <version> 2.22.2</version>-->
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
          <junitxml>.</junitxml>
          <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>



</project>
```

Please help me debug this , Thanks in Advance.
I have seen many similar errors here in stackoverflow,
and so I went to check if spark 2.4.3 has Internal Logging or not , and I see it is present  - [SPARK_2.4.3_DOCUMENTATION](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.html)
Which is why i am not sure what wrong I am doing here.
My Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Libraries -
[image: Libraries]

Comment: which IDE are you using ??

Comment: @Srinivas, I am using - Intellij IDEA 2020.1.1 ( Community )

Comment: can you show me image  of - go to File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> click on Libraries

Comment: @Srinivas, I have added the snapshot of my Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Libraries

Comment: Check these threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069372/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-internal-logging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287289/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-logging

Comment: @Andrey, Thanks for those links, I tried all those solutions but all resulted with the same result. Interestingly , when I ran the the same code ( packaged as JAR )  in Databricks, the code executed without any of these issues. But this observation only deepens the issue here.