# IntelliJ: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, sbt

**PS. There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287289/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-logging), but that is in mvn and my project is in sbt.**

First up, a few required informations:

- Spark Installed Version: 2.4.0
- Scala Installed Version: 2.11.12

I'm trying to run [this](https://dzone.com/articles/basic-example-for-spark-structured-streaming-amp-k) project inside IntelliJ IDEA, for which my `build.sbt` looks like:

```
name := "kafka-latest-spark-streaming"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.0" % "provided",
    "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.11.0.1"
)
```

The main application code is similar to the one in the tutorial apart from a few imports I had to make to make implicits like `$` work. When I try to run the scala file by right click and selecting `Run 'Main'`, it throws the below error:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=59919:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/sparker0i/kafka-latest-spark-streaming/target/scala-2.11/classes:/Users/sparker0i/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.12.jar:/Users/sparker0i/.ivy2/cache/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4/jars/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/Users/sparker0i/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/jars/kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:/Users/sparker0i/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/sparker0i/.ivy2/cache/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/bundles/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're trying to run spark as a local app from your IDE (master set as `local[n]`), you need to remove **provided** from your dependency definitions.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0", //provided removed
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.0", //provided removed
    "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.11.0.1"
)
```

On the other hand, when you'll be running your app on spark cluster you'll need to set spark dependencies as provided. You can just override dependencies with provided versions on certain tasks (like `assembly`).

Another thing you can do is just clicking on the checkbox `Include dependencies with "Provided" scope` on run configuration and whenever you would run your project from IntelliJ all *provided* dependencies should be included.

[image]

Comment: Even after removing `% "provided"` IntelliJ could still throw `NoClassDefFoundError`. I found IntelliJ restart is necessary to alleviate the problem.

Comment: Yes, you have to wait until Intellij processes changes in build.sbt. Probably `build > rebuild project` would also work.